# Create Query For MYSQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

First i have 2 tables named "item" and "buy_item"
//the "stock" column is in item table and the "qty" column is ini buy_item table
then I have SQL SERVER query to create a trigger like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
ON dbo.buy_item
FOR UPDATE 
AS begin 
UPDATE item SET stock = stock - qty FROM deleted WHERE item.id = deleted.id 
UPDATE item SET stock = stock + qty FROM inserted WHERE item.id = deleted.id 
end
```

I need help to create the same function of this query in MYSQL query
and i already do this

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
BEFORE UPDATE ON buy_item
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE item SET stock = stock - buy_item.qty WHERE item.id=buy_item.id
UPDATE item SET stock = stock + NEW.qty WHERE item.id=buy_item.id
END
```

but this isn't work at all, it says the syntax is wrong

maybe anyone can help about this

Thanks before

Comment: Please include any relevant error messages in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can't change item id in `buy_item` your trigger in MySql should look like this

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
AFTER UPDATE ON buy_item
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE item 
     SET stock = stock + NEW.qty - OLD.qty
   WHERE id = NEW.id;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6600d/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

A trigger body in mysql requires a number of SQL commands separated by a semi-colon (;). To create the full trigger code one must define its own delimiter to something else — such as $$.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 
BEFORE UPDATE ON buy_item 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE item SET stock = stock - buy_item.qty WHERE item.id=buy_item.id;
UPDATE item SET stock = stock + NEW.qty WHERE item.id=buy_item.id; 
END$$
```

This web site as helped me in the past for syntax and other relevant issues to mysql and triggers
http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/

Comment: i have already try to do it, but it still ask me to make the right syntax near this syntax

Answer (score 0):

this is the error message after i write the syntax

> DELIMITER $$ 
>   CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 
>   BEFORE UPDATE ON buy_item 
>   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
>   UPDATE item SET stock = stock - buy_item.qty WHERE item.id=buy_item.id; 
>   UPDATE item SET stock = stock + NEW.qty WHERE item.id=buy_item.id; 
>   END$$

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger1 
BEFORE UPDATE ON buy_item 
FOR EACH ROW' at line 1'"

My MySQL server version is 5.5.13